# How to solve formula parse error when using setFormulaR1C1 in Google Apps Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, multidimensional-array

I would like to use getFormulasR1C1 / setFormulasR1C1, but I get a formula parse error as some of the cells in the source range do not contain any formula. This does not occur when using getFormulas / setFormulas, only with the R1C1 version (but I need relative cell references, so I need the R1C1 version anyway).

I read in the documentation [here (for getFormulasR1C1)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulasr1c1) and [here (for getFormulas)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas) that :

- For getFormulasR1C1, "Entries in the 2D array are null for cells with no formula"

whereas…

- For getFormulas, "Entries in the 2D array are empty strings for cells with no formula"

So I guess maybe I could take the array and replace null entries by empty string. Tried something like this :

```
var formulasAndNull = sh.getRange(headingRow+1, firstCol, 1, sh.getLastColumn()- 
firstCol+1).getFormulasR1C1();
var formulas = [[]];
for (var i in formulasAndNull[0]){
if(formulasAndNull[0][i] == null)
formulas[0].push('')
else
formulas[0].push(formulasAndNull[0][i])
}
```

Does not work at all, still have formula parse errors when setting the formulas.

What is quite strange is when I do this :

```
var formulasAndNull = sh.getRange(headingRow+1, firstCol, 1, sh.getLastColumn()-firstCol+1).getFormulasR1C1();
var formulas = [[]];
for (var i in formulasAndNull[0]){
if(formulasAndNull[0][i] == '')
formulas[0].push('50')
else
formulas[0].push(formulasAndNull[0][i])
}
```

Then it seems to work a bit : I now have '50' in the cells that did not contains formulas (but I'd just need empty strings !). And this is the same if I replace `if(formulasAndNull[0][i] == '')` by `if(formulasAndNull[0][i] == 0)`.

How could I get a correct array so setFormulasR1C1 would work properly ?

I must say there is a quite easy way to obtain the result I want, quite efficient but not very elegant… : just copyTo() and then getFormulas / setFormulas on the destination range to delete values. Something like this :

```
sh.getRange(sourceRow).copyTo(destinationRow);
sh.getRange(destinationRow).setFormulas(destinationRow.getFormulas());
```

But I don't really like it…

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that `Range.setFormulasR1C1()` always expects valid formulas and does not let you send a `null` or empty text string to signify a blank cell. The pattern you mention last is probably the best way to accomplish what you ask for. To get blanks in cells that have no formulas, use `Range.copyTo()` and `setValues()` instead of `setFormulas()`, like this:

```
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetRange)
  targetRange.setValues(targetRange.getFormulas());
```

[Range.getFormulas()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformulas) gets a zero-length text string `''` when a cell doesn't contain a formula. When you use [Range.setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) to write into cells, and a value is a formula, the target cell will contain a formula rather than a text string. When the value is a zero-length text string, the cell will be blank.